# How to access SQLite Database created in SQLiteManager in Android App?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have a database created in SQLiteManager from Mozilla, I exported it and saved the .sql file in assets folder, now how do I read or make entries in this database from my android app? How should my DatabaseHandler( which extends SQLiteOpenHelper) should look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it directly from the assets/. You need to copy it to a file (internal or external storage) the app can access directly. Then open as usual.

More details here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: I read somewhere that it needs to be placed in assets, where should I keep it? Please elaborate your answer, I'm new with database.

Comment: You need to put it in assets in order to include it in the package APK. To use it at runtime, you need to copy it to a file (which assets isn't). See article link above.

Comment: @AyushGoyal: The same issue is answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728